alternative solution to dbt_utils.get_column_values() for a dbt model
I was trying to ser a variable in a dbt model.
However I am struggling to overcome a issue that I encounter. From my understanding dbt_utils.get_column_values() doesn't work with CTE, however for overcoming that, i build an auxiliary model to mimic the cte and build a table.
From this table (see print shot bellow), I want to fetch the maximum levels between a string, the leves would be split by /

so for that I build this model:
--/models/dim_product/stg/stg_aux_calculate.sql

select max(LENGTH(VALUE) - LENGTH(REPLACE(VALUE, '/', '')))::integer as max_splits
from {{ source('schema', 'category_tbl') }}

And this will generate this table (using snowflake):

From here I create a new model, that wants to pick that value 5 in set it as variable
 -- will need to add 1 to account for the original string (tackle after)
 --/models/dim_product/stg/stg_category_model.sql

{%- set max_splits = dbt_utils.get_column_values(
    table = ref('stg_aux_calculate'), 
    column = 'max_splits')[0] -%}

with split_values as (
    select
        value_id,
        value,
        {% for i in range(1, max_splits) %}
            split_part(value, '/', {{ i }}) as value_component_{{ i }},
        {% endfor %}
        ATTRIBUTE_ID,
        ENTITY_ID,
        STORE_ID
    from {{ source('schema', 'category_tbl') }}
)

select
    value_id,
    value,
    {% for i in range(1, max_splits) %}
        max(value_component_{{ i }}) as value_component_{{ i }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    ,
    ATTRIBUTE_ID,
    ENTITY_ID,
    STORE_ID
from split_values
group by value_id,value, ATTRIBUTE_ID, ENTITY_ID, STORE_ID 

The error that I get is TypeError: 'Undefined' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
I know that this works because if I hardcode the variable with:
{% set max_splits = 6 %}

It will return what I expect:

On snowflake the stg_aux_calculate.sql model gets created like this
    create or replace view DEV_etc.DBT_my_name_xyz.stg_aux_calculate(
    MAX_SPLITS
) as (
    select max(LENGTH(VALUE) - LENGTH(REPLACE(VALUE, '/', '')))::integer as max_splits
from DEV_RAW_INT
.conf.CATALOG_CATEGORY_conf
  );

Any suggestion for overcome this?

Via claire - get_column_values is not compatible with CTEs, as it relies on the object you pass it being a table or view in the database. Here is a workaround: Write your own macro, get_column_values_from_query, which does the same thing as get_column_values but doesn’t depend on being passed a table or view. See https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/using-get-column-values-with-ctes/1423

your second approach (having a separate model and ref'ing it in the macro) should work. Can you share more code from that? Also, why are you adding a [0] at the end?

@AleixCC I'm adding [0] to make sure that I will pick the first value from max_splits even though the model aux_model only generates a table with 1 row and 1 column with 1 value. If I don't put the [0] I get this error TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer and if I put [0] it I get error TypeError: 'Undefined' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. I also tried to cast max_splits as integer, but doesn't fix. The idea is to use the variable with the number that comes from aux_model inside a jinja loop, I know that works if I hard code a number (ex. 6).

cool. but you definitely need to share more context on where you are using that set. Without that, it's very difficult to help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@AleixCC update my example with more info, I believe it's more complete like this.

I've done some toy, working example on my end. Let's see:
-- my_splits_model.sql // this will just return an integer

select 5 as max_splits

-- my_downstream_model.sql

{%- set max_splits = dbt_utils.get_column_values(
      table = ref('my_splits_model'),
      column = 'max_splits'
    )[0]
-%}

-- we want to make sure that the `max_splits` variable is an actual number
{% if max_splits is number %}
select 
    '{{ max_splits }}' as this_is_my_max_splits
  {% for split in range(1, max_splits) %}
    , 'split_number_{{ split }}' as split_{{ split }}
  {% endfor %}

{% else %}
select 'hmmm' as that_is_not_a_number

{% endif %}

This last model compiles to:
select
    '5' as this_is_my_max_splits
  
    , 'split_number_1' as split_1
  
    , 'split_number_2' as split_2
  
    , 'split_number_3' as split_3
  
    , 'split_number_4' as split_4

If I update my_splits_model.sql to return something that's not an integer:
-- my_splits_model.sql // this will now not return an integer

select 'some text' as max_splits

Then my_downstream_model will compile to:
select 'hmmm' as that_is_not_a_number

So, to your use case: I would just make sure, by using Jinja's builtin test is number, that what you actually get from the max_splits set is an actual number.

I was able to do a workaround with your suggestions. Dropped the cte and built 2 models and inside the models started always with {% if max_splits is number %} and in the {% else %} I updated with the same code but with a control variable c{% set control_value = 10 %} . It's doing what I want. Don't really understand why only inside the macro when {% if max_splits is number %} it works. Might be some limitation on dbt. Thanks the help!

Good! FYI you can also "accept" the answer as the person who asked the question, so that it is flagged to others that it helped resolve your issue :)
